# Convert Pyspark Dataframe column from array to new columns

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I've a Pyspark Dataframe with this structure:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Q: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- pr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- qt: double (nullable = true)
```

Something similar to:

```
 +----+--------------------- ... --+
 | Id |           Q                |
 +----+---------------------- ... -+
 | 001| [ [pr1,1.9], [pr3,2.0]...] |
 | 002| [ [pr2,1.0], [pr9,3.9]...] |
 | 003| [ [pr2,9.0], ...         ] |
  ...
```

I wold like to convert Q array into columns (name pr  value qt).
Also I would like to avoid duplicated columns by merging (add) same columns.

```
 +----+-----+-----+------+ ... ----+
 | Id | pr1 | pr2 | pr3  | ... prn |
 +----+-----+-----+------+ ... ----+
 | 001| 1.9 | 0.0 | 2.0  | ...     |
 | 002| 0.0 | 1.0 | 0    | ...     |
 | 003| 0.0 | 9.0 | ...  | ...     |
  ...
```

How can I perform this transformation?.
Thakyou in advance!!.
Julián.

Comment: Hi, let me know if the answer worked or you have any other questions, thx

Comment: Yes  ags29, thank you!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `explode` and `pivot`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# explode to get "long" format
df=df.withColumn('exploded', F.explode('Q'))

# get the name and the name in separate columns
df=df.withColumn('name', F.col('exploded').getItem(0))
df=df.withColumn('value', F.col('exploded').getItem(1))

# now pivot
df.groupby('Id').pivot('name').agg(F.max('value')).na.fill(0)
```

Comment: I get `Field name should be String Literal, but it's 0` when running `df=df.withColumn('name', F.col('exploded').getItem(0))`
`df=df.withColumn('value', F.col('exploded').getItem(1))`

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question.   This is how I approached it.

test.csv

```
001,pr1:0.9,pr3:1.2,pr2:2.0
002,pr3:5.2,pr4:0.99
```

Pyspark

```
file = sc.textFile("file:///test2.csv")

//get it in (key,value)
//[(u'001', u'pr1:0.9')...]

//rdd1 = file.map(lambda r: r.replace(",","\t",1)).map(lambda r: r.split("\t")).map(lambda r: (r[0],r[1])).flatMapValues(lambda r: r.split(','))
rdd1 = file.map(lambda r: r.split(",")[0]).map(lambda r: (r[0],r[1])).flatMapValues(lambda r: r.split(','))

//create a DF with 3 columns
//[(u'001', u'pr1', u'0.9')...)]
+---+---+----+
| _1| _2|  _3|
+---+---+----+
|001|pr1| 0.9|
|001|pr3| 1.2|
|001|pr2| 2.0|
|002|pr3| 5.2|
|002|pr4|0.99|
+---+---+----+


rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda r: (r[0],r[1].split(":"))).map(lambda r: (r[0],r[1][0],r[1][1]))
df = rdd2.toDF()


//Perform the magic
df.groupBy("_1").pivot("_2").agg(expr("coalesce(first(_3),0)"))


+---+---+---+---+----+
| _1|pr1|pr2|pr3| pr4|
+---+---+---+---+----+
|001|0.9|2.0|1.2|   0|
|002|  0|  0|5.2|0.99|
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: Thak you Bala, It's a good solution. Maybe a little bit longer than the proposed by ags29.