# Extract columns from a list of lists in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am stuck trying to extract columns from a list of lists but can't visualize how to do it.  I am fairly new to spark.  Running pyspark on Spark 2.4.3.

I have a json organized like this:

```
{ "meta" : { ... },
  "data" : 
  [[ "a", 0, null, "{ }"],
   [ "b", 0, null, "{ }"],
   [ "c", 0, null, "{ }"],
   ] }
```

I want to get the 'data' portion into columns, like

```
 +------+------+------+------+
 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
 +------+------+------+------+
 |   a  |   0  | None | "{ }"|
 |   b  |   0  | None | "{ }"|
 |   c  |   0  | None | "{ }"|
```

I have my dataframe read in and printSchema() shows this.

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- meta: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- view: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- approvals: array (nullable = true) ...
```

My rough shape is 70 columns by 650k rows.

I was able to explode the df to get just the `data` portion but am stuck there.

Comment: You can access the individual elements of the array through `getItem` function as shown here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874037/convert-pyspark-dataframe-column-from-array-to-new-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode the rows first, and then select the array elements using `[]` in Python.

```
df2 = df.select(F.explode('data').alias('data')) \
        .select(*[F.col('data')[i].alias('col%s'%(i+1)) for i in range(4)])

df2.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   a|   0|null| { }|
|   b|   0|null| { }|
|   c|   0|null| { }|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use just SparkSession.createDataFrame() method?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame

You can provide data and schema parameters to this method and get spark dataframe.

Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data)
```

If spark cannot infer schema from the data then schema also need to be provided

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

struct = StructType()
struct.add("col1", "string", True)
struct.add("col2", "integer", True)
struct.add("col3", "string", True)
struct.add("col4", "string", True)


df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=struct)
```

In addition, you can use pyspark type classes instead of python primitive type names.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.types

module contains both simple types(StringType, IntegerType, ...) and complex types(ArrayType, MapType, ...)

Last note: data cannot contain `null`, it should be `None` in python. spark DataFrame.show() will print `None` columns as `null`.

Comment: I didn't want to specify schema as I have 70 columns.