# Extract field in rows in array to columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I am struggling with extracting values from array of rows into columns on the highest level.
Short version of the spark dataframe is as follows

```
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- specifications: array (nullable = true)  ## lots of specs here, ~20, they must go to columns
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- speccode: long (nullable = true)   # to ignore
 |    |    |    |-- specdecryption: string (nullable = true)  # to ignore
 |    |    |    |-- specname: string (nullable = true)   # column name
 |    |    |    |-- specvalue: string (nullable = true)  # to value in that column
 |    |-- begin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: long (nullable = true)
 |-- kafka_offset: long (nullable = true)  # to ignore
```

Field "specifications" is array and contains approx. 20 Rows each of them has its own keys and values. Keys are the same for all rows. Value in specname must become column name, specvalue must go into value in that column.

```
'specifications': 
[Row(speccode=123, specdecryption=None, specname='Color', specvalue='red'),
 Row(speccode=234, specdecryption=None, specname='Power', specvalue='155'),
 Row(speccode=134, specdecryption=None, specname='Speed', specvalue='198'),
 Row(speccode=229, specdecryption=None, specname='Length',specvalue='4658'),...]
```

I need to convert it into a dataframe columns

```
|  date     |id | spec_color| spec_power| spec_speed| spec_length|  begin   |   end    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2023-08-29| 1 |   red     |  155      |  198      | 4698       |2023-08-29|2023-08-30|
| 2023-08-29| 2 |  blue     |  199      |  220      | 4540       |2023-08-29|2023-08-30|
```

Comment: This should help you. almost exact question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874037/convert-pyspark-dataframe-column-from-array-to-new-columns

Answer (score 0):

Extract the relevant columns from `data` struct then use inline on `specifications` column to explodes an array of structs into a table afterward pivot the dataframe to reshape it.

```
cols = ['date', 'id', 'begin', 'end']

(
    df
    .select(*[F.col('data')[c].alias(c) for c in cols + ['specifications']])
    .select(*cols, F.inline('specifications'))
    .withColumn('specname', F.expr("'spec_' || lower(specname)"))
    .groupby(*cols).pivot('specname').agg(F.first('specvalue'))
)
```

---

```
+----------+---+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|      date| id|     begin|       end|spec_color|spec_length|spec_power|spec_speed|
+----------+---+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|2022-02-03|  2|2022-06-02|2022-06-01|       red|       4658|       155|       198|
|2022-02-06|  1|2022-06-02|2022-06-01|       red|       4658|       155|       198|
+----------+---+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
```